# Relative url not working for home page when welcome page is set

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-editor-web-part, relative-path

I have created an HTML snippet which references a js file stored in **site assets** folder.

The path to this file in my snippet is as

```
../SiteAssets/MyJsFile.js
```

In SharePoint, welcome page is set to `[siteURL]/pages/home.aspx`

Now In `home.aspx`, I have added a content editor web part having reference to above HTML snippet.

If I open home page using `[siteURL]/pages/home.aspx` everything works perfectly, but if I open site using `[siteUrl]` in the browser then it starts giving `404 error` for my js file.

How can I resolve this issue, does it mean in SP we can not give a relative path for the home page?

Comment: Is siteassets library on the root of the site? Then just use /siteassets/myjsfile.js

Comment: aspx pages are in Pages library, while html and js files are in site assets folder.

Comment: I have this exact same problem. Did you come up with a decent solution, other than having to hard code the full path? I wish we could prevent SP from using the "/" URL for site home (Welcome) pages. i.e. always force the full path, including /pages/default.aspx...

Comment: nope. For home page I had to hard code the path, but for all other pages I am using relative path.

Answer (score 1):

Always refer the JS/CSS paths either with SP tags or starts with site url

for eaxmple.
Site URL: http://www.oursharepointsite/
JS Ref URl : "/SiteAssets/MyJsFile.js"

SubSite URL: http://www.oursharepointsite/subsite/
JS Ref URl : "/subsite/SiteAssets/MyJsFile.js"

It works wherever your page resides, no matter how you refer the file either with  Designer or webpart.

Comment: could you please explain why ../ wont work?

Comment: Due to Alternate access mapping which redirects to welcome page based on zone

Comment: Thanks Shive, but it makes me update my html when ever I have to deploy other site :(

Comment: in this case you can try sharepoint token... ~site/SiteAssets/MyJsFile.js,

Try..;like we do in webpart JS link

Answer (score 0):

Consider you have a Root Site and your JS files within SiteAssets library in it `http://rootsite`

- So the relative URL should be

> `/SiteAssets/MyJsFile.js`

If  your JS files within a SiteAssets library in a subsite `http://rootsite/subsite` and you need to use it at home page of root site,

- So the relative URL should be

> ```
> ../SiteAssets/MyJsFile.js
> ```

Based on your question you should use `/SiteAssets/MyJsFile.js` instead of `../SiteAssets/MyJsFile.js`

Comment: why does ../ wont work?

Comment: As I mentioned above it depends on the location of your JS files every ../ represent subsite , Is you tried to use /SiteAssets/MyJsFile.js is it worked ? please don't hesitate if you need more clarification

Comment: Yes it works, but the problem is if I need to use this in other SPO site, then I have to update the references in the HTML file